# Problem loading content within a jQuery UI tab

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui, tabs

It was working earlier today... :S but now, whenever I click a link in the tab, it opens in an entirely new page, regardless of whether the tab contents are embedded in the current page, or referenced from another.

Here's my code, and thanks in advance!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" media="screen,projection" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--  <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
  });
  </script>

<!----Javascript edited in below----->
      <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#payday').tabs({
    load: function(event, ui) {
        $('a', ui.panel).click(function() {
            $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
            return false;
        });
    }
}); 
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="headercon">
                </div><!--headercon-->
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div><!-- header -->

            <div id="tabs">
            <div id="navigation">

                    <ul>
                        <li class="selected"><a href="#nav1"><span>nav1</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="form2.php"><span>nav2</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="form3.php"><span>nav3</span></a></li>
                    </ul>

                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div><!-- navigation -->

            <div id="info">
            <div class="top"></div>
            <div id="payday" class="middle">
<h3>Get a quick quote NOW! <a href="form2.php">google</a></h3>
<div class="information">
<form action="ajax.php" id="submit" method="post">
<p class="enter"><span>Email address:</span><br><input id="email" class="email" type="text" name="email" value="Enter your email" input onclick="this.value='';" /></p>
<p class="date"><span>Date of birth:</span><br><input id="dd" class="day" type="text" name="dd" value="DD" input onclick="this.value='';"/><input id="mm" class="month" type="text" name="mm" value="MM" input onclick="this.value='';"/><input id="yyyy" class="year" type="text" name="yyyy" value="YYYY" input onclick="this.value='';"/></p>
<p class="submit"><input class="button" type="submit" value="" /></p>
</form>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div><!--information-->
<div class="success" style="display: none;">added.</div>  
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div><!--middle-->
                                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div><!-- navigation -->
```

Comment: We need more info here please. What does your JavaScript look like?

Comment: Can you check your version control history and see what you changed?

Comment: Whoops, accidentally left that out. I've edited the post and added that back in. Any ideas now? Thanks! :)

Comment: Martinho, how do I do that? [mind you, it's been edited a LOT today. I'm not sure how much that'd help :( ]

Comment: Do a diff on a revision from earlier in the day.

Comment: @eoJ: If the change is buried with lots of others, I usually do a binary search: checkout a commit that I know works, test it to confirm, pick a commit between that and the non-working one, test it, etc, narrowing down the range between a known-working and a known-not-working commit, until I find the change responsible. (`git bisect` helps a lot).

Comment: "mind you, it's been edited a LOT today. " - you are using source code control, right?

Comment: Could you post a minimal demo to a site, [like JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), that reproduces your problem?

Comment: Tomalak & Martinho - I would, but unfortunately I'm on shared hosting, so no SSH access, and I've been editing it all in cpanel code editor "/

Comment: Mitch - No, I'm not... lesson learnt.

Comment: David - that site doesn't seem to give a very good representation of it. Since this is for my own small project, I'll post the website. http://www.loansforpeoplewithbadcredit.biz   Thanks for all the help everyone! I Really Really appreciate it - been trying to make the site work properly all day today and yesterday "/

Comment: so any ideas at all anyone? I just tried adding the code to my local copy, for some reason it's not even working on that... :S

Comment: Do you think the two javascript codes relating specifically to the tabs might be interfering with one another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code included in your link, you're missing the `#` on payday:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#payday').tabs({ // <<< see here
    load: function(event, ui) {
        $('a', ui.panel).click(function() {
            $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
            return false;
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

However, I'm not experiencing any issues with the tabs coming or the page going to the link instead. I'm using FF4.

Your approach is flawed using `.tabs()` to load content like this. Just use `.load()` or `.get()`.

Example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#single a').click(function(e){
        $('#target').load(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="single">
    <a href="files/test1.php">Test 1</a>
    <a href="files/test2.php">Test 2</a>
    <a href="files/test3.php">Test 3</a>
</div>
<div id="target"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The next thing you would need to do is handle the links within the loaded content. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setLink('single');
});

function setLink(id){
    $('#'+id+' a').click(function(e){
        $('#target').load(
            this.href,
            function(){
                setLink('target');
            }
        );
        return false;
    });
}
```

See http://jfcoder.com/test/load.php.

**EDIT 2**

To load the first A link in the list onDOMReady (instead of onLoad):

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    setLink('single');
    $('#target').load($('#single a:first').attr('href'));
});

function setLink(id){
    $('#'+id+' a').click(function(e){
        $('#target').load(
            this.href,
            function(){
                setLink('target');
            }
        );
        return false;
    });
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="single">
    <a href="files/test1.php">Test 1</a>
    <a href="files/test2.php">Test 2</a>
    <a href="files/test3.php">Test 3</a>
</div>
<div id="target"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

See http://jfcoder.com/test/load.php also.

Comment: Ah, nice one noticing that. I just changed it though, it still doesn't work :(

And yeah, the tabs in general are working fine, but I need the link in the payday tab to open without leaving the page, because then I'll be able to make the form submit work. Any ideas? Cheers loads for the help! :)

Comment: Wow, that's awesome, that knocks hundreds of lines of code off my css :D I've added it. I dunno whether I've done it wrong, though, it's still opening links in a new tab :( Sorry to be annoying.

Comment: @eoJ - See my edit. My guess is that you're not setting up the links in the loaded content.

Comment: Brilliant, it worked! I think it was that I was putting the target div in the wrong place. Thanks SO MUCH! :D Just wondering, how would I make it load the first page in the target onload? Thanks SO MUCH for that solution, that's absolutely awesome :)

Comment: @eoJ - See my edit. You want to do it onDOMReady, because you need the page to load first.

Answer (score 0):

You close the `#navigation` div, but you don't close the `#tabs` div? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Ah, sorry, that didn't get included. I did close it, but the </div> is just below that last one. Thanks though :)